# How Do You Autopopulate Attribute Based on Spatial Location of Underlying Grid?? ArcGIS Mobile

Tags: editing, mobile, arcgis-mobile

User drops a point, then Attribute Table Autopopulates based on Underlying (Polygon)Grids Spatial Location.

I want to do this for field editors using ArcGIS Mobile.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS for Mobile are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the point's location to query the underlying grid. When you get the results, you can autopopulate the point's attributes. You can either use a QueryTask to query an individual grid layer, or an IdentifyTask if you want to get data from multiple grid layers.

Or, if you had access to a geoprocessing service, you could run a [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Spatial_Join/00080000000q000000/) operation on the point against whatever polygon features you wish. It will return a point with all the attributes from the features the point intersected.